# Python Text parsing - Do you know why the double empty quotes appear where for me there is nothing in between?

Tags: python, json, regex, pymongo

I'm parsing a file with many lines such as the following one:

```
ocngPrbSerie : [{prbFirst=0, prbLast=0, pdschModType=QPSK_MOD_SCH, usedSubFrameNo=[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]}, {prbFirst=0, prbLast=0, pdschModType=QPSK_MOD_SCH, usedSubFrameNo=[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]}]
```

What I'm trying to do is put into quotes everything except structure (meanning [[]{},=\s:) to insert into mongodb database after rebuild the string once the quotes are put in place. I want to leave the numbers without quotes as well.

What I have so far:

```
    f = open(filepath, "r")
    for line in f:
        x = re.split("([\[\]{},=\s:])", line)
        print(line)
        i = 0
        while i < len(x):
            if re.search("([\[\]{},=\s:])",x[i]) is None:
                x[i] = "\u0022" + x[i] + "\u0022"
            print(x[i])
            i = i+1
```

The result is quite as expected, in terms of putting the quotes, but as you can see in the print of the firsts lines of the result, some lines are like this "" (double empty quotes) but if you check the line I'm processing there is nothing between [ and { but the print appears like [ "" {

> "ocngPrbSerie"
>
> **""** : **""**
>
> **""** [ **""** { "prbFirst"
>   = "0" , **""**

Do you know why the double empty quotes appear, where for me there is nothing in between?

Also any improve in the code is welcome, I'm kind a newbie in python.

Many thanks

Comment: I think you need to remove the capturing parentheses: `x = re.split("[][{},=\s:]", line)`

Comment: Probably, `r"[][{},=\s:]+"` is even better since it will match 1 or more occurrences of these chars.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - Your presumed duplicate question is not what the OP asks. From his code in the `while i < len(x)` loop it is evident that he is aware that _the groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list._ What he misses and asks about are obviously the empty elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Do you know why the double empty quotes appear, where for me there is nothing in between?

This question is easy to answer - if the string to split has adjacent occurrences of the separator (as the space and the colon in your example), an empty element results between them.

> Also any improve in the code is welcome …

I'd just specify in the regular expression what to replace (i. e. every word that begins with a letter), and do it all in one `re.sub()`:

```
    f = open(filepath, "r")
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        print(re.sub('[A-Za-z]\w*', '"\g<0>"', line))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The expected output should be like this:

"ocngPrbSerie" : [{"prbFirst"=0, "prbLast"=0, "pdschModType"="QPSK_MOD_SCH", "usedSubFrameNo"=["false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false"]}, {"prbFirst"=0, "prbLast"=0, "pdschModType"="QPSK_MOD_SCH", "usedSubFrameNo"=["false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false"]}

Everything quoted except the "special chars" used as separators in my original code and numbers. And skipping empty elemnts.

Regards